# Changes to .o files after compiling

Tags: kernel, c, system-call-fastboot

I have built a custom kernel and I am able to do my system call,but now I want to change the logic in the .o file reference in the Makefile

> obj-y += sys_calls_test.o

the sys_calls_test.o has

```
#include<linux/linkage.h>
asmlinakge long sys_hello(void)
{
printk("hello");
}
```

I modified it to

```
#include<linux/linkage.h>
asmlinakge long sys_hello(void)
{
printk("Testing this block");
}
```

When I try to recompile my sys_calls_test.c file the changes are not showing up

I used

```
gcc file_name.c -o testing_comp
./testing_comp
```

My sys_calls_test.c file that I have referenced in the kernel's makefile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define sys_hello 349

int main(void)
{
    int c = syscall(sys_hello, a, b);
    printf("System call returned %d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

**I am still seeing "Hello there" and not "Testing this block"**

Can someone point me if I have to recompile the linux source and why my changes are not showing up. Should I need to use the make command and rebuild the entire kernel source to show this change since I have changed the .o reference in the Kernel's Makefile

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.o files are compiled directly into the output executable, so if you want your changes to appear you will have to recompile the kernel that depends on it.

You are thinking of dynamically linked/shared-object files, which in linux are generally saved out as .so files.

Please refer to this stackoverflow question for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688200/difference-between-shared-objects-so-static-libraries-a-and-dlls-so

Comment: So is this the reason people prefer modular programming against system programming ?